# Не работает код, который показывает и скрывает блоки

Tags: javascript

```
$(function() {
    $(".showMenu").on("click",function() {
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("hideMenu");
        $(this).find("span").text("Показать меню навигацию");
        $(".sidebar .sideBlock").fadeIn(0);
        $(".sidebar .catalog").fadeOut(0);
        return false;
    });
    $(".hideMenu").on("click",function() {
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("showMenu");
        $(this).find("span").text("Спрятать меню навигацию");
        $(".sidebar .catalog").fadeIn(0);
        $(".sidebar .sideBlock").fadeOut(0);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: что не работает, как не работает? выдает ошибку? ничего не делает? делает что-то неожиданное?

Comment: Необходимо добавить в вопрос соответствующий HTML и CSS код, а также подробно описать что должно происходить.

Answer (score 2):

> – Ваша программа не работает.
>   – A little man crawled out of the computer and told you so?

Мы (те, которые не телепаты) не знаем, какие классы есть у элемента в момент назначения обработчиков `click`. Так как Вы манипулируете классами, то обработчики лучше присвоить ближайшему родителю, который точно существует, указав соответствующий селектор в `$().on`. Тогда обработчик будет выстреливать для подэлементов DOM как существующих, так и созданных (или измененных так, что они начинают подходить под селектор) потом.

```
$(".showMenu").on("click", function() {
  ...
  $(this).addClass("hideMenu");
  ...

$(".hideMenu").on("click", function() {
  ...
  $(this).addClass("showMenu");
  ...
```

изменить на

```
$(document).on("click", ".showMenu", function() {
  ...
  $(this).addClass("hideMenu");
  ...

$(document).on("click", ".hideMenu", function() {
  ...
  $(this).addClass("showMenu");
  ...
```

Comment: почему? поясните

Comment: _A little man crawled out of the computer and told you so?_ эм... что это значит?

Comment: тогда уж надо было полностью переводить :-)

Comment: Хотя некоторые утонченные пользователи способны углядеть сарказм и в этом.